# How to turn Variadic Templates into multiple single templates?(C++ Competitive Programming Debugging Template)

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

My debugging template is:

```
#define ts to_string 
string ts(char c) { return string(1, c); }
string ts(bool b) { return b ? "true" : "false"; }
string ts(const char* s) { return (string)s; }
string ts(string s) { return s; }
template<class A> string ts(complex<A> c) { 
    stringstream ss; ss << c; return ss.str(); }
string ts(vector<bool> v) { 
    string res = "{"; for(int i = 0; i < si(v); ++i) res += char('0' + v[i]);
    res += "}"; return res; }
template<size_t SZ> string ts(bitset<SZ> b) {
    string res = ""; for(int i = 0; i < SZ; ++i) res += char('0' + b[i]);
    return res; }
template<class A, class B> string ts(pair<A,B> p);
template<class T> string ts(T v) { // containers with begin(), end()
    bool fst = 1; string res = "{";
    for(const auto& x: v) {
        if (!fst) res += ", ";
        fst = 0; res += ts(x);
    }
    res += "}"; return res;
}
template<class A, class B> string ts(pair<A,B> p) {
    return "(" + ts(p.f) + ", " + ts(p.s) + ")"; }

void DBG() { cerr << "]" << endl; }
template<class H, class... T> void DBG(H h, T... t) {
    cerr << ts(h); if (sizeof...(t)) cerr << ", ";
    DBG(t...); }
#ifdef LOCAL // compile with -DLOCAL
#define dbg(...) cerr << "[" << #__VA_ARGS__ << "]: [", DBG(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define dbg(...) 0
#endif
```

When I type

```
dbg(a, n);
```

where 'a' is the vector name and n is the size of the vector. 'a' contains the following {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and n = 5

it prints

```
[a, n]: [{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 5]
```

but I want it to print

```
[a]: [{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]
[n]: [5]
```

without having to type

```
dbg(a);
dbg(n);
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Overload the macro on number of arguments and invoke that macro for each argument you pass.

Comment: Can you please describe? Maybe the code for doing it? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeforces community has helped me and told me the correct solution.

```
#define ts to_string
string ts(char c) { return string(1, c); }
string ts(bool b) { return b ? "true" : "false"; }
string ts(const char* s) { return (string)s; }
string ts(string s) { return s; }
template<class A> string ts(complex<A> c) { 
    stringstream ss; ss << c; return ss.str(); }
string ts(vector<bool> v) { 
    string res = "{"; for(int i = 0; i < si(v); ++i) res += char('0' + v[i]);
    res += "}"; return res; }
template<size_t SZ> string ts(bitset<SZ> b) {
    string res = ""; for(int i = 0; i < SZ; ++i) res += char('0' + b[i]);
    return res; }
template<class A, class B> string ts(pair<A,B> p);
template<class T> string ts(T v) { // containers with begin(), end()
    bool fst = 1; string res = "{";
    for (const auto& x: v) {
        if (!fst) res += ", ";
        fst = 0; res += ts(x);
    }
    res += "}"; return res;
}
template<class A, class B> string ts(pair<A,B> p) {
    return "(" + ts(p.f) + ", " + ts(p.s) + ")"; }
 
// DEBUG
void DBG(string names) { string s = names; }
template<class H, class... T> void DBG(string names, H h, T... t) {
    auto pos = names.find(',');
    auto first_name = names.substr(0, pos);
    auto rest = names.substr(pos+1);
    // Strip space at the beginning
    while(rest.front() == ' '){
        rest = rest.substr(1);
    }
    cerr << "[" << first_name << "]: [" << ts(h) << "]" << nl;
    DBG(rest, t...);
}
#ifdef LOCAL
#define dbg(...) DBG(#__VA_ARGS__, __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define dbg(...) 0
#endif
void EDBG() { cerr << "]" << endl; }
template<class H, class... T> void EDBG(H h, T... t) {
    cerr << ts(h); if (sizeof...(t)) cerr << ", ";
    EDBG(t...); }
#ifdef LOCAL // compile with -DLOCAL
#define edbg(...) cerr << "[" << #__VA_ARGS__ << "]: [", EDBG(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define edbg(...) 0
#endif
```

the macro

```
edbg
```

does not do it seperately so

```
edbg(a, n);
```

will output

```
edbg(a, n);
```

Whereas

```
dbg(a, n);
```

will output

```
dbg(a);
dbg(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
When I type

    dbg(a, n);

I want it to print

    dbg(a);
    dbg(n);

Is there any way to do this?
```

Overload a macro on number of arguments and invoke your callback in the overload for each argument.

```
// renamed from dbg
#define dbg_in(...) cerr << "[" << #__VA_ARGS__ << "]: [", DBG(__VA_ARGS__)

// overloads
#define dbg_1(_1) \
        dbg_in(_1)
#define dbg_2(_1,_2) \
        dbg_1(_1);dbg_in(_2)
#define dbg_3(_1,_2,_3) \
        dbg_2(_1,_2);dbg_in(_3)
// etc.
#define dbg_N(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,N,...) \
        dbg_##N
#define dbg(...) \
        dbg_N(__VA_ARGS__,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)(__VA_ARGS__)

dbg(a, b);
// expands to: dbg_in(a);dbg_in(b);
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it has the same output as the original debug function. For example when I write a simple inputting a vector and outputting the vector values and the size of the vector, it    is the same.

Comment: [Works for me, godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/jhXPnj)

Comment: Well, you have to fill the `// etc.` part if you want more overloads : ) and if you want more then 10 you have to add more `_10,_11,_12,...` and `12,11,10,9,...` to macro arguments lists.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this other than manually putting in 4 elements for dbg, 5, 6, 7, 8, .... Is there any easier way?

Comment: Not with macros. For macros you have to explicitly generate all possible combinations - it's generally a text replacement.  Still, you do that once (preferably with a script) and live happy. Many projects use boost.preprocessor (or I remember P90 projects) or similar projects that come with a version of "FOREACH" macro.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `#__VA_ARGS__` doesn't return a list of strings, comma separated, with the names of the variables, but a single string, with the name of the variables comma separated.

So you have to split the string in some way.

If you can use C++17, I propose the following function that take a single string, with names comma separated, and return a `std::vector<std::string>` with single names

```
std::vector<std::string> splitWords (std::string const & s)
 {
   std::regex rgx ("\\w+");

   return { std::sregex_token_iterator{s.begin(), s.end(), rgx},
            std::sregex_token_iterator{} };
 }
```

and also a variadic templates `dbgh()` (dbg helper) function as follows

```
template <typename ... Ts>
void dbgh (std::vector<std::string> v, Ts const & ... ts)
 { 
   std::size_t i{};

   ((std::cerr << '[' << v[i++] << "]: [", DBG(ts)), ...);
 }
```

so you can write the `dbg()` variadic macro as follows

```
#define dbg(...) dbgh(splitWords(#__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)
```